# Why pytorch's nn.ModuleList don't support vectorization? Does the following code have performance problem?

Tags: pytorch, vectorization

I have many subnetworks in my model, and for different samples, I want use different subnetwork to do some calculation. After do some searches, I find the following way. Why pytorch's nn.ModuleList don't support vectorization? Does this method have performance problems?

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class SingleVariableNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, init_value):
        super(SingleVariableNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.v = torch.tensor([init_value], dtype=torch.int32) 
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.v * x

class IndexedNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, networks):
        super(IndexedNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.networks = networks

    def forward(self, x, network_indices):
        outputs = []
        for i in range(x.size(0)):
            network_input = x[i]
            # only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index
            network_output = self.networks[network_indices[i]](network_input)
            outputs.append(network_output)
        return torch.stack(outputs)

networks = nn.ModuleList([SingleVariableNetwork(i) for i in range(5)]) 
indexedNetwork = IndexedNetwork(networks)
input = torch.tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
indices = torch.tensor([3, 0, 2, 1, 4])
result = indexedNetwork(input, indices)
print(result)
```

I try to write like the forward function of class IndexedNetwork like this:
`return self.experts[expert_index](expert_input)`
but pytorch raise error with massage "only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index"

Answer (score 0):

You can't broadcast inputs along a `nn.ModuleList`. The module list is just a python list with extra features for parameter tracking.

If your sub-networks are all the same architecture, you should be able to vectorize inputs at the tensor operation level. For example, changing the `self.v` parameter to a vector (representing sub-models) and the input `x` to a vector as well.